# mysqli extension is missing in phpMyAdmin on RedHat 5.9 Server

Tags: phpmyadmin, rhel-5

We have installed Apache, PHP, MySQL, and attempted to install phpMyAdmin. When going to phpMyAdmin in the browser, we are presented with "The mbstring extension is missing."

We are unable to get into phpMyAdmin. When we try to install php-mbstring we are presented with php53-common conflicts with php-common. This is being done on a Red Hat 5.9 Server.

We installed mbstring by doing

```
yum install php53-mbstring
```

Now we receive the following error "the mysqli extension is missing..." in phpMyAdmin. We added `extension=mysqli.so` into our php.ini file, but the issue persists.

Comment: yum install php-mysqli did the trick! Then stop and start Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Is `php-mysql` installed?

```
$yum info php-mysql
```

will tell you (it should say `installed` next to `Repo`).  Install it with:-

```
#yum install php-mysql
```

If it was installed, have you restarted Apache since installing it?